# virtualenv command not found in El Capitan

Tags: macos, python, osx-el-capitan

OS: Mac OS X 10.11.1 (El Capitan)
Python: Homebrew Python 2.7.10
pip: 7.1.2 (latest)

I installed virtualenv by `pip install virtualenv`, the installation was successful. But when I typed `virtualenv`, the bash prompted `command not found`.

I looked into the path `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` and `/usr/local/bin` but found no executable `virtualenv`.

How to install and run `virtualenv` correctly in El Capitan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the exact same setup, and when I `pip install virtualenv`, the executable symlink is added to `/usr/local/bin` as expected. So it seems like the install your install is not actually successful.

Did you try using to `find` or `locate` to search for `virtualenv`? Try `sudo find / -name virtualenv 2>/dev/null`.

Since you're a Python developer, you can load up your favorite debugger or editor (I like Spyder, pudb, PyCharm, and Sublime Text) and debug `pip` itself. Set a breakpoint (or print statements, whichever) at [pip/req/req_install.py:L795](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/7.1.2/pip/req/req_install.py#L795). Not far from there it will complete the install by moving the appropriate files.

Comment: I reinstall virtualenv and it worked. I guess it is due to the network issue.

Comment: I uninstalled & reinstalled virtualenv several times, and it did not work. Then suddenly, I tried it one more time, and now it works and is installed to `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv`. ???

Answer (score 1):

I guess it installed into `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`. Some python packages tend to install into this directory under El Capitan. You should therefore find a way to install into the correct directory.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem on *Mac OS X El Capitan*.

When I installed *virtualenv* like that `sudo pip3 install virtualenv` I didn't have *virtualenv* under my command line.

I solved this problem when I switched to super user account by calling `sudo su` and then installed *virtualenv* like that `pip3 install virtualenv`. Finally I could access *virtualenv* from both user and super user account. Remember to uninstall previous installations before you switch to super user account.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update pip then reinstall virtualenv! That work for me